# If you use a set of variables to calculate the target, can those variables be used as features?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, predictor

For example, lets say I have some data on a set of products. This includes the cost of bringing the product to market and the total purchase amount of the product. Let's say I introduce a new variable "profits" that I calculate by subtracting marketing costs from total purchases.

For example:

| product name | total purchases | marketing costs | profits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lemonade | \$43 | \$10 | \$33 |

If I'm trying to build a model that predicts profits (regression) or a model that predicts whether or not a product is profitable (i.e. whether the profits are greater than or below 0) (classification), could I include total purchases and marketing costs as features? Or is that not okay since I used those variables to calculate profits, which is what I'm trying to predict?

Comment: Some additional context might be useful, but some initial thoughts. 1) Including total purchases and marketing costs will clearly create a model that is not very helpful, since profits is a deterministic function of those two features.

Comment: 2) Consider what happens if you use total purchases (for example) as a feature in a regression. Then the "true" model will be E[profits | total purchases] = total purchases - E[cost | total purchases]. Essentially, if you take your fitted model and add back total purchases, you will find that your model is actually just predicting E[cost | total purcahses]. This is all to say that fitting a model with total purchases as a feature is not logically contradictory, but in this case, it would have been more direct/transparent to just model cost as a function of total purchases.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your example here:

**profits = total_purchases -   marketing_costs**

This is a precise equality. There is no uncertainty or source of error.

Because your response is simply a linear combination of your predictors, basic maths will give you perfect predictions! A statistical model would not add any anything of value - you wouldn't learn anything new or gain predictive ability.

So it's worth stepping back and thinking about what you are trying to achieve with your analysis.